# Errors with an on-premise connection (with .Net Core 3.1 on Docker)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core

I currently run a `.Net Core 3.1` application on `Docker` *(with `Nginx` as reverse proxy)*, on an EC2 instance.

I've got an on-premise database (and a VPN tunnel between my VPC and my on-premise router) but when I try to connect to the database, I've got an error and I can't find where it come from and how to fix it.

Here is the stack trace :

```
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |       An error occurred using the connection to database 'TEST_MANHATTAN' on server '192.168.1.7\sql2012'.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |       An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'ManhattanPlatform.Areas.Identity.Data.OnPremiseContext'.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |       Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |        ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |        ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |        ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] recvBuf, Int32 recvOffset, Int32 recvCount, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, ArraySegment`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |       ClientConnectionId:8e308087-4105-4b69-bd4b-ae51089678c4
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    | Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |  ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |  ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |  ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] recvBuf, Int32 recvOffset, Int32 recvCount, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, ArraySegment`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    |    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
Base_backend.1.l4u8imxbglsf@ip-192-168-100-188    | ClientConnectionId:8e308087-4105-4b69-bd4b-ae51089678c4
```

Comment: Can you share your connection string (with sensitive information redacted), please? Perhaps you need `TrustServerCertificate=True` set?

Comment: Here is my connection string : "OnPremiseContextConnection": "Server=192.168.1.7\\sql2012;Database=[XXXX];User id=[XXXX];Password=[XXXX]TrustServerCertificate=True;"
But as you can see I've already tried the TrustServerCertificate (lol) but it seems that everything come from the SQL Server that hasn't been updated since 2018 (so it does not support TLSv1.2)

Comment: Might be a copy-paste error in your comment, but there's a missing semi-colon between the password and `TrustServerCertificate`.

Comment: Yeah I've erase it by mistake, sorry ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that both Client (Container) and the SQL Server are talking in different language, i.e. TLS 1.2 or TLS1.3 and either of these is not supported by the SQL Server you are trying to connect. Check the version of SQL Server and patch it has to determine the TLS and SSL ciphers supported by it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

After some research, we found that the server hasn't been updated since 2018...

We will try to update it and check again if everything works. I keep you informed of further events